# Load a different .env Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodes

I have two files, .env.exmaple and .env.LUIGI
I set the APP_NAME with value LUIGI in Config Vars on Heroku (I tried even from terminal, same result)

in my app.js I use:

```
dotenv.config({ path: process.env.APP_NAME !== undefined ? '.env.example' : '.env.'+process.env.APP_NAME });
```

When I deploy my app, heroku gets the vars from .env.example.
I print the value of `process.env.APP_NAME` in my page and I can read LUIGI.

I can get the result that I'm looking for with

```
heroku local web -e .env.LUIGI
```

in my local

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `.env` file on Heroku at all. `.env` files are simply a convenient way to set environment variables in development. Heroku's equivalent is [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Just set those and you're done.

Comment: thanks Chris, I 'd like to store base64 image in my config vars, but it's too long

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/927

Comment: ...what possible reason could you have to store an image this way? This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).